# How to fix "warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]" for empty virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a base class with a number of empty virtual methods which are implemented in the various subclasses, like so:

```
//base class (has no attribute A or B)
virtual double getAttributeA(){} //implemented in subclass A
virtual int getAttributeB(){} // implemented in subclass B
```

I need the empty functions because I need to call the subclass functions on base class pointers.

This compiles fine, but I get a warning because I obviously defined a return type (the ones the subclasses need) but do not return anything.

How can I resolve this warning?

Thanks!

Comment: Return something.

Comment: Why the braces?

Comment: Are these methods only supposed to be implemented by some subclasses, not all? It seems like a questionable design.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes exactly. They are actually getters/setters for attributes which only subclass A or B have respectively. Do you have an idea how I could do it better?

Comment: @juanchopanza The methods are getters/setters. The base class, however doesn't have all the attributes of the subclasses. So I can't return the attributes. Would returning some random value instead be good style?

Comment: You could `throw` an exception, but the best solution probably involves more of a redesign than that.

Comment: Either (1) return something as suggested by  @juanchopanza or (2) make them pure. This is rather basic.

Comment: Why do you want to resolve the warning if it compiles fine?

Comment: If A and B derive from Base, but A has some attributes that are not in B, or vice versa, then their getter/setters do not belong in Base to begin with. Only things that are common to both A and B should be in Base.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input! I have manoeuvred myself into a dead end with this. I need to work with a vector of pointers of base class, all of which point to objects of my sub classes. To be able to call the sub classes' methods, I need to put the sub class methods into the base class header. I cannot make the functions pure in base bc I need to implement them in all sub classes then (same problem, they don't have all attributes + means a lot of useless code). I'll probably go with returning 0 in the base class. If anyone has a better idea how to handle this whole thing, pls let me know.

Answer (score 4):

> I need the empty functions because I need to call the subclass functions on base class pointers.

They do not need to be empty if you declare them as pure virtuals instead, eg:

```
virtual double getAttributeA() = 0;
virtual int getAttributeB() = 0;
```

This means the base class itself does not require implementations at all, but derived classes must implement them.

> I get a warning because I obviously defined a return type (the ones the subclasses need) but do not return anything.

If you declare a non-void return type, you must return something:

```
virtual double getAttributeA() { return 0.0; }
virtual int getAttributeB() { return 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have already tried your first solution, however that doesn't compile because I need to implement the functions in **all** subclasses then. And not all subclasses have all the same attributes. I might go with returning 0 though.

Comment: @hsvar attributes that do not apply to all subclasses not belong in the base class to begin with.